# Progress bar in a for in os.listdir() with model.predict() inside the loop

Tags: python, for-loop, progress-bar, tqdm

I have a simple for loop that works in this way:

```
for filename in tqdm(os.listdir('train')):
    path = os.path.join('train', filename)
    for i in range(9):
        features = model.predict(some_array)
```

Where model is a keras model used for feature extraction, so model.predict() is the classical method.
As you can see I tried to use tqdm to see the progress of the loop, for example if my directory has 5 files, I would expect to see a progress bar that tells me how much files I already passed through. Instead with my code, I get 5 small progress bars like:

> 1/1 [==============================] - 0s 31ms
> 1/1 [==============================] - 0s 47ms
> 1/1 [==============================] - 0s 47ms
> 1/1 [==============================] - 0s 30ms
> 1/1 [==============================] - 0s 32ms

How can I solve?

Comment: Take a look at [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please post all relevant code, not some placeholder. Also run it on a directory with 5 entries and paste the output. Then don't `print` anything inside the loop.

Comment: @CristiFati now I wrote it in the way you suggested. By doing some test I discovered that the root of the problem is the function model.predict() so that's the only relevant code inside the for loop